# How can I select only elements which are first children of a container by class?

Tags: html, css

I have complex blocks of DIVs netted to one another and I cannot edit them because this html code is provided from the system.  Only thing I could do is from CSS.

I want to select only "Child 1".  My CSS does select "Child 1", but because of some related class netted to one another, it selects "Grand child 1" and "Great grandChild 1", as well, unfortunately!

Please give me a hand on how to select only "Child 1".

Thanks!

```css
.container > .child:first-child {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
Parent
  <div class="child">
    Child 1
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    Child 2
     <div class="container">
        Child of Child 2
        <div class="child">
          Grand Child 1
        </div>
        <div class="child">
          Grand Child 2
          <div class="container">
            Parent
              <div class="child">
                Great grandChild 1
              </div>
                <div class="child">
                  Great grandChild 2
              </div>
            </div>
        </div>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5):

This will only select `.container` that not child of the `.child`.

```css
:not(.child) > .container > .child:first-child {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
Parent
  <div class="child">
    Child 1
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    Child 2
     <div class="container">
        Child of Child 2
        <div class="child">
          Grand Child 1
        </div>
        <div class="child">
          Grand Child 2
          <div class="container">
            Parent
              <div class="child">
                Great grandChild 1
              </div>
                <div class="child">
                  Great grandChild 2
              </div>
            </div>
        </div>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: yeah it's right if we know which parent is the first. so we can select like `.something > .container > .child:first-child`.

Comment: So far it's the only answer that matches OPs requirements generically enough to not tie it to the expectancy of a specific DOM structure *aside* of the code shown.

Answer (score 0):

`.child:first-child:is(:not(.child *))` will select elements with class `child` which are first element children of their parents and have no ancestors with class `child`.

Comment: What if accidentally they had a `<body class="child">` in their page? You are making assumptions about the DOM structure that aren't backed up by the information presented in the question.

Comment: I'm making assumptions which I consider sensible. Other answers assume even more. The question isn't very formal in its statement of the problem. I explain precisely what my code does. It's also minimalistic, thus easier to understand and adapt (one of the goals of SO being to accumulate knowledge helpful to others, not only OPs), uncluttered by accidental stuff like including `.container` somewhere.